structured attribute split from the class with association to another class
I have a class E1, with a structured attribute, associated with a class E2 with many-to-many multiplicity. During the creation of the conceptual schema I separate the structured attribute from E1 by creating a class E3. Must the new E3 class always participate in the association with many-to-many multiplicity, changing the binary association to ternary?
